# Receive feedback from SonarQube in regards to design and architecture

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-metrics, sonarqube5.3

I am analyzing a code base consisting of mainly Java which is quite large (~1 million lines of code) using SonarQube, Jenkins and Bitbucket.

More to the point, one of the main tasks of this analysis is to investigate how the architecture and design of this code-base can, using SonarQube analysis and plugins, be improved. What I have found during my research is that there used to be a matrix which did somewhat what I am looking for, i.e. the SonarQube Dependency Structure Matrix, however that is depreciated as of this time.

I also found the complexity metric to look use to investigate the level of complexity each file/class/method has but I am looking for more advanced design and architecture feedback if possible.

Here are my plugins in my SonarQube Server (running v5.3) which I am using as of this time:

- Checkstyle v2.4
- Findbugs v3.3
- Git v1.1
- Java 3.11-build4121
- Java Properties v1.5
- PMD v2.5
- SVN v1.2

That is, what I am looking for is information regarding how SonarQube can be used to find architectural  flaws or areas of improvements using software metrics or similar. During my research I have not found any clear relationships to how SonarQube can be used for this purpose.

Thus, my question is how SonarQube and certain plugins can be used to find architecture and design improvements (by viewing the different changes over time e.g.) in a code-base?

I am happy for any feedback or questions you may have.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, the dependency matrix has been removed. It would have likely been unusable for you anyway - which is partly why it was removed.

As you also note, there are rules about class and method complexity. Additionally, you'll find complexity metrics at the project, module, directory, and file level. (Click through on 'Structure'.) Those should help you pinpoint some hotspots.

<strike>The Java rule [Cycles between packages should be removed](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3ACycleBetweenPackages) may help as well</strike> (**EDIT**: that rule was dropped in Java Plugin 4.0), as might the duplication-related metrics.

Beyond those things, I don't think the advanced design and architecture feedback you're after is really available.

What I don't think is going to do much for you in this area are the CheckStyle, PMD, and FindBugs plugins. Most valuable rules from the first two have been replaced by the Java plugin, and a majority of FindBugs rules have also been replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your great response!

Are you aware of any other useful plugins for this purpose?

Is it still worthwhile to keep the plugins (Checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs) installed or are they superfluous to most other purposes (i.e. finding anomalies and issues) aswell? The reason why I am wondering is if they slow down the analysis process since the server has to check the same rules twice etc.

Comment: IMO, you could uninstall those plugins; particularly for your stated purpose. I might advise holding on to FindBugs a little longer if your focus were not architecture. As far as other potentially helpful plugins, I scanned [the Other Plugins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Other+Plugins) page before I submitted my answer and didn't find anything convincing. It's possible the [Structure101 plugin](http://structure101.com/help/java/build/#sonar/sonar.html) would apply, but its documentation looks out of date, and it appears to be for integration with a commercial product.

Comment: The mentioned Java rule seems not to be available anymore. Has it been replaced by some other rule?

Comment: It was dropped without replacement